# angularjs dynamically pass in a JSON when checkbox is changed

Tags: angularjs

```
        <li ng-repeat="header in table.headers track by $index">


            <div data-ng-if="header.type === 'checkbox'">
                {{header.value}}<input type="checkbox"
                ng-init="table.addBoxInputs[$index] = {type: 'checkbox', checked: false, value: header.value}"
                />
            </div>
```

So my program dynamic generate a checkbox, and it passes in a json initially. Now I want that json's `checked` key to change to `true` or `false`, depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

I don't want to make a method in controller and change it, is there a way to do it in the markup? I tried adding the following:

```
  ng-model='table.addBoxInputs[$index]'
  ng-change="table.addBoxInputs[$index] = {type: 'checkbox', checked: table.addBoxInputs[$index], value: header.value}"
```

However this wont work, cause the ng-model will just keep changing the table.addboxinput[$index] to either true or false, base on checkbox

Comment: first off... you have some attribute quote problems in the thing you tried.

Comment: Could you update your post to include the contents of the 'table' object?

Comment: @jbrown, the table object contains a lot of stuff, it might just cause confusion. the table.addBoxInput is just an empty array in the beginning.
 to: kevin B: my bad I made a mistake when I was copying. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a proponent of doing this in your markup but if that's how you want to do it then you will need to add the ng-click directive to your check box like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="table.addBoxInputs[$index] = {type: 'checkbox', checked: false, value: header.value}" ng-click="table.addBoxInputs[$index].checked = !table.addBoxInputs[$index].checked" />
```

Here's a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJDHFJpXAnqL4D04OtBG?p=preview).